# Windows 8: Video preview only shows first frame

Tags: windows-8, video, thumbnails, preview

I just switched from 7 to 8, but it seems MS changed the way the explorer displays the video preview icons. I think that 7 skipped into the video a few frames, or even took a frame with more colour? Does someone know how this worked? In 8 it only displays the first frame of the video, which makes it difficult to identify the girls I want to watch.

Is there some way to use the superior functionality of 7 again? It seemed as if it had some magic face detection system, or is the preview picture already pre-saved in the mp4 format?

EDIT: In 8 it doesn't seem to be the first frame either, because some videos are displayed nicely, but other are displaying a mostly black background with some text. Windows 7 displayed them all nicely.

Comment: Girls? What kind of videos are these?

Comment: See if [this](http://superuser.com/questions/496689/how-to-enable-thumbnail-previews-for-my-non-standard-mp4-avi-mov-mkv-video-fil) helps.